# RestEasy resets all headers when resource throws an exception

Tags: java, cors, resteasy

I've uncovered something strange while using resteasy-jaxrs in a Cors enabled jBoss server.  Here's the setup:

Our server has thetransactioncompany.com's CorsFilter (v1.3.2) enabled as a servlet filter to enable CORS and add the appropriate CORS headers to the HttpServletResponse object.

The server itself is using resteasy-jaxrs (v2.3.2.Final) to serve JSON endpoints to power our app, obviously running on a separate domain.

The issue is that if one of my endpoint methods generates any type of exception (NPE, UnauthorizedException, InternalServerErrorException), as a part of preparing the response, RestEasy makes the call

```
(HttpServletResponse)response.reset()
```

which clears out my CORS headers.  This causes Chrome to rightly act as if the request should be canceled.  This is really inconvenient for my front end dev who needs those error codes.

Two questions:

1. Why would RestEasy want to clear those headers?
2. Has anyone else run across this and have any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I am actually surprised to see that you have encountered this behavior since I've never seen it, and I certainly have generated plenty of exceptions in my day.

Regardless, consider writing a custom `ExceptionMapper` as described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.4.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#ExceptionMappers). You can populate the response with your CORS headers and return it from `toResponse` along with the appropriate error information.

Comment: True, I could reset the header in an exception mapper, but that duplicates the logic done by the CORS servlet filter.  I'd rather not do that, but it may be the only way. Your comments suggests that some other configuration is incorrect, but I've traced through the code and see that any "uncaught" exception contains a call to response.reset().

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue too, and I had a workaround by using a response wrapper

```
class CorsHeaderResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper{

    public CorsHeaderResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse resp) {
        super(resp);
        setCorsHeader();
    }

    void setCorsHeader(){
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse)getResponse();
        //set cors header here
    }

    public void reset(){
        super.reset();
        //set again if anyone reset it
        setCorsHeader();
    }

}
```

when calling doFilter

```
chain.doFilter(req, new CorsHeaderResponseWrapper(resp));
```